The impact of private vs state ownership on social welfare: Theory
There are plenty of theories on private ownership, for example: State versus Private Ownership.
There are also plenty of theories on social welfare, for example Pareto efficiency, Samuelson, Arrow's impossibility, general equilibrium, Sen, behavioral welfare, and many more.
Are there any theoretical papers on the effect of state/private ownership on social inequality and welfare?

what exactly you mean by social inequality? There is lot of various work in economics about income, wealth, consumption and so on inequality, but I never seen social inequality being discussed. How do you define and measure it?

I think it is enough to discuss income inequality and inequality of receiving life-necessities such as water, gas, and electricity.
